# Generate static HTML page from Django pages

Tags: python, html, django

I have a small web site developed in Django. I want to generate static HTML pages from that web site.

e.g.

```
{% include "commondata.html" %}
```

will be replaced by the HTML page content.

How can I do that?

Comment: That is exactly what `include` is for

Comment: I know but I want to generate that automatically via a generator

Comment: Can you explain more about what the expected result would be?